# Print power of string/array

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Given an integer array nums of unique elements, return all possible subsets (the power set). The belwo code is returning wrong answer for input [1,2].How to fix it?

> Expected Output is
>
> [[],[1],[2],[1,2]]

I have written the code here which works fine.But i wanted to know why we are doing
https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/735373452/

```
output.remove(output.size()-1);
```

But in the same code i don't do backtrack but it still print all power sets

```
String s = "ABC";
                ps(s, 0, "");
public static void ps(String str, int i, String ans) {

        if (i == str.length()) {
            System.out.println(" Print " + ans);

            return;
        }

        ps(str, i + 1, ans + str.charAt(i));
        ps(str, i + 1, ans);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you are creating *2 ^ n* Strings during the recursive call, where *n* is the length of `str`. While the code in leetcode is using a single List. Adding elements to the List will have influence after the method call, thus need to remove the element to "restore" the List.

---

In Java, Strings are immutable. In your recursive `ps` function, you are creating new Strings with `ans + str.charAt(i)`, the original `ans` remains the same. Therefore you don't need to use the backtracking.

```java
// say ans == "A", and str.charAt(1) == "B":

ps(str, i + 1, ans + str.charAt(i));
ps(str, i + 1, ans);

// will be called as:
ps("ABC", 2, "AB");
ps("ABC", 2, "A");
```

In the leetcode code, it's using a List. All the recursive calls share the same List. Modifying the list will impact the following calls. If we add an element before calling the function, we need to remove the element after calling the function.

```java
// ans is a List now, not String: ans == ['A', 'B']
ans.add(str.charAt(i));   // ans == ['A', 'B', 'C']
ps(str, i + 1, ans);  // ps("ABC", 3, ['A', 'B', 'C'])

// ans is still ['A', 'B', 'C']
// we want to call ps("ABC", 3, ['A', 'B']) now:
ans.remove(ans.size() - 1);
ps(str, i + 1, ans);
```

Perhaps you are thinking that maybe changing the order will work:

```java
ps(str, i + 1, ans);

ans.add(str.charAt(i));
ps(str, i + 1, ans);
```

It still has the problem if not calling `ans.remove(str.charAt(ans.size() - 1)`. You can try changing the type of `ans` to `List<Character>` or `StringBuilder` in your `ps` function, and print `ans` during each recursive call.